# Distance between start and end date BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I'm trying to write a query that calculates the distance between the start and end date for each  ID. I'm not interested in the points between those date ranges. I only need to grab the lat/long of the start and end date and calculate the euclidean distance.

Table 1 looks like this:

```
    ID     startdate     enddate
    A      2016-9-16     2016-10-9
    A      2017-3-18     2017-4-9
```

Table 2 has the coordinates and looks like this:

```
ID  Date        Latitude      Longitude
A   2016-9-16   40.76        -109.33
A   2016-9-17   40.72        -109.33
A   2016-10-9   40.75        -109.33
A   2017-3-18   40.81        -109.33
A   2017-4-8    40.83        -109.33
A   2017-4-9    40.96        -109.32
```

My desired results would look like:

```
ID t1.startdate   t2.Latitude t2.Longitude t1.enddate t2.Latitude t2.Longitude  distance
A   2017-3-18    40.81       -109.33      2017-4-9    40.96       -109.32      150
A   2016-9-16    40.76       -109.33      2016-10-9   40.75      -109.33       200
```

This is as close as I've gotten but since there can be multiple ID's, it's not matching the correct start and end dates for each ID:

```
SELECT
t1,t2, 
ST_DISTANCE(Point1, Point2 ) as distance
from (
SELECT
    ID, 
      st_geogpoint(Longitude,Latitude) as Point1
      from `t2` AS t2 INNER JOIN  
      `t1` AS t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        WHERE  t1.ID = t2.ID AND
        t2.Date = t1.startdate ) t1,
          (
   SELECT 
        ID, 
        st_geogpoint(Longitude, Latitude) as Point2
        from `t2` AS t2 INNER JOIN  
       `t1` AS t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        WHERE  t1.ID = t2.ID AND
        t2.Date = t1.enddate
    ) t2
WHERE  t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Current results look like:

```
ID t1.startdate   t2.Latitude t2.Longitude t1.enddate t2.Latitude t2.Longitude  distance
A   2016-9-16    40.76       -109.33      2016-10-9    40.75       -109.33      150
A   2016-9-16    40.76       -109.33      2017-4-9     40.96      -109.32       250
A   2017-3-18    40.81       -109.33      2017-4-9     40.96      -109.32       200
A   2017-3-18    40.81       -109.33      2016-10-9    40.75      -109.33       250
```

Comment: Could you explain "it's not matching the correct start and end dates"? Maybe table2 is missing data for some ID and Date?

Comment: Edited the question with more information. There can be multiple records in table 1 with the same ID, which is causing the matching issue in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this may solve your problem:

I use t1 as the source and `JOIN` t2 twice on the dates (start & end) then reference those in the `ST_DISTANCE`. There maybe a quicker/may performant way to solve this.

```
WITH t1 as (
        SELECT 'A' AS ID, '2016-9-16'AS startdate, '2016-10-9' AS enddate
        UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2017-3-18', '2017-4-9'
), t2 as (
SELECT 'A' AS ID,'2016-9-16' AS date, 40.76 AS Latitude, -109.33 AS Longitude    
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2016-9-17',40.72,-109.33 
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2016-10-9',40.75,-109.33
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2017-3-18',40.81,-109.33
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2017-4-8',40.83,-109.33
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','2017-4-9',40.96,-109.32
)

SELECT
  t1.ID, 
  start_point.date AS start_date,
  start_point.Longitude AS start_long,
  start_point.Latitude AS start_lat,
  end_point.date AS end_date,
  end_point.Longitude AS end_long,
  end_point.Latitude AS end_lat,
  ST_DISTANCE(
    ST_GEOGPOINT(start_point.Longitude,start_point.Latitude), 
    ST_GEOGPOINT(end_point.Longitude,end_point.Latitude)) AS distance

FROM t1 
JOIN t2 AS start_point
ON t1.id = start_point.id AND t1.startdate = start_point.date

JOIN t2 AS end_point
ON t1.id = end_point.id AND t1.enddate = end_point.date
```

*Results:*

| Row | ID | start_date | start_long | start_lat | end_date | end_long | end_lat | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2016-9-16 | -109.33 | 40.76 | 2016-10-9 | -109.33 | 40.75 | 1111.9510117740244 |
| 2 | A | 2017-3-18 | -109.33 | 40.81 | 2017-4-9 | -109.32 | 40.96 | 16700.437093959285 |